# Please help me with selecting the appropriate test for a measurement

Tags: hypothesis-testing, measurement, psychology

I am a freshman psychology major and have coursework to write scientific papers. I have found a topic that I am interested in and I also have found the journal. I have read the journal but could not understand which test to use in this measurement. Probably because I haven't learn that too. But, I already choose that topic and must continue it anyway.

So, if any of want to spare a bit of your time and explain this to me that would be VERY helpful. This journal can be found [HERE](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2489543)

Bearden, W. O., Netemeyer, R. G., & Teel, J. E. (1989). *Measurement of Consumer Susceptibility to Interpersonal Influence*. Journal of Consumer Research, 15(4), 473. doi.org/10.1086/209186

Comment: Please post the full citation of the article; you can get this from Google Scholar. Links can break, but the citation will stick around.

Comment: Bearden, W. O., Netemeyer, R. G., & Teel, J. E. (1989). Measurement of Consumer Susceptibility to Interpersonal Influence. Journal of Consumer Research, 15(4), 473. https://doi.org/10.1086/209186